# jQUery Autocomplete not generating anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

My Autocomplete does not work, Im just building a simple one and cant get it to work,

```
$(function() {
    var data = ["1200-1399", "1100-1199", "3400-3409", "5000-5999", "6000-6999", "7000-7120", "9050-9059", "9550"];
    $( "#inputBox" ).autocomplete({
        source: data
    });
});
```

This is all the jQuery code that I use, and this is the html one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bigWrapper">

    <div id="content">
        <div id="formContainer" class="column">
            <form name="bankClearNr" method="GET">
                <label for="inputBox">Clearing</label>
                <input id="inputBox" type="text" name="inputBox" class="ui-front">
                <button class="right" type="button" id="confirmButton">&nbsp;Ok&nbsp;</button>
                <br><br>
                <label for="outputBox">BankID</label>
                <input type="text" id="outputBox" disabled>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't you miss jQueryUI stylesheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `class="ui-front"` from `input` and it will work.
The `css` seems messed up but I guess it's missing your custom `main.css`, i.e.:

```
<input id="inputBox" type="text" name="inputBox">
```

### ----------

```js
$(function() {
    var data = ["1200-1399", "1100-1199", "3400-3409", "5000-5999", "6000-6999", "7000-7120", "9050-9059", "9550"];
    $( "#inputBox" ).autocomplete({
        source: data
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bigWrapper">

    <div id="content">
        <div id="formContainer" class="column">
            <form name="bankClearNr" method="GET">
                <label for="inputBox">Clearing</label>
                <input id="inputBox" type="text" name="inputBox" class="ui-widget">
                <button class="right" type="button" id="confirmButton">&nbsp;Ok&nbsp;</button>
                <br><br>
                <label for="outputBox">BankID</label>
                <input type="text" id="outputBox" disabled>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
 
  
 
  
  
  
</body>
</html>
```